# Python while loop in Jupyter notebook not executing

Tags: python, python-3.x, while-loop, jupyter-notebook

I am new to python programming, I executed this problem in C but I can resolve it in Python as its not throwing error on Jupyter notebook, just an asterisk on the cell.

I have cycled the list so as to avoid the index out of bounds error.
Please help

```
s='UDDDUDUU'
n=8
s=list(s)
seaLevel=0
valley=0
li=[]
for i in s:
    if i=='D':
        seaLevel-=1
        li.append(seaLevel)
    elif i=='U':
        seaLevel+=1
        li.append(seaLevel)
i=0
j=0
while i<n:
    if li[i]==0 and li[(i+1)%n]<0:
        valley+=1
        j=i+1
        while li[j]<0 and j<n:
            j=+1
        i=j
    else:
        i+=1
valley
```

Comment: Add some print statements in to check that your list is populated. Also, are you meaning to ```print(valley)``` at the end?

Comment: Yeah sorry actually I was working on jupyter notebooks.

Answer (score 3):

An asterisk on the cell often indicates that you have an infinite loop and the code snippet does not terminate. This is exactly the case with your code - your while loop is an infinite loop.

```
while i<n:
    if li[i]==0 and li[(i+1)%n]<0:
        valley+=1
        j=i+1
        while li[j]<0 and j<n:
            j=+1 !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
        i=j
    else:
        i+=1
```

Your typo is specifically `j=+1`, which is equivalent to `j=(+1)`, whilst `j+=1` is `j=j+1`. `j=+1` always set `j=1`, and so your `i=j` always set `i=1`, and therefore your while loop never terminated.

**TL;DR**: Change your `j=+1` to `j+=1`. And don't forget to add print statement for `valley`, as kindly mentioned in comments.

Answer (score 0):

Isn't the line 21 a typo? It seems the line keeps making `j==1`, along with i.